# Obtener solamente registros con el valor mas alto en su agrupación - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo un query que me trae el ID de empleado con su departamento y la sucursal donde trabaja. Sin embargo quiero que me regrese solamente los empleados con valor en ventas mas alto de su departamento.
El query que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
SELECT a.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL,a.NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO,a.ID_EMPLEADO, SUM(a.PRECIO) 
as "TOTAL VENTAS" 
FROM tbl_facturas a
GROUP BY a.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL,a.NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO,a.ID_EMPLEADO
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si existe un metodo para hacer un filtro y obtener solo el empleado con mayor ventas

Comment: Si, un empleado por departamento y sucursal

Comment: Tengo la versión 8.0

Comment: Se me ocurre con un **CTE**  donde primero obtienes la sumatoria de las ventas, después por fuera obtienes el máximo de las ventas, agrupas por sucursal y agrupas por la sucursal haber si es lo que ocupas y sirve `WITH primerConsulta AS(
 SELECT a.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL,a.NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO,a.ID_EMPLEADO, SUM(a.PRECIO) 
 as TOTALVENTAS 
 FROM tbl_facturas a
 GROUP BY a.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL,a.NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO,a.ID_EMPLEADO
)
SELECT a.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL, a.NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO, a.ID_EMPLEADO, MAX(TOTALVENTAS)
FROM primerConsulta GROUP BY a.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL;`

Comment: No puedo usar la clausula WITH, supongo que no estoy en 8.0

Comment: entonces prueba con esta **subquery** `SELECT a.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL,a.NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO,a.ID_EMPLEADO, MAX(TOTAL_VENTAS)
FROM
 (
  SELECT a.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL,a.NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO,a.ID_EMPLEADO, SUM(a.PRECIO) 
  as TOTAL_VENTAS
  FROM tbl_facturas a
  GROUP BY a.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL,a.NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO,a.ID_EMPLEADO
 ) foo
GROUP BY a.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL,a.NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO,a.ID_EMPLEADO;`

Comment: si le quito el campo a.ID_EMPLEADO, del ultimo group by parece funcionar